# nodetool not run when cassandra service is started by java code

Tags: service, cassandra

I started my CassandraDaemon thread not as service in windows using [services.msc] but by the following code.

```
public static void start() {
    if (cassandraDaemon == null) {
        cassandraDaemon = new org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon();
        cassandraDaemon.activate();
    }
}
```

The above code starts the cassandra service and I tested it,it works.But nodetool.bat file not run.

When I use the following command `nodetool -h IPADDRESS info` it produce

> Failed to connect to 'IPADDRESS:7199': Connection refused: connect

as reply.

I added following one during init

```
System.setProperty("cassandra-foreground","true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote","true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.port","7199");

System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate","false");
System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl", "false");**
```

What should i Add in coding by that nodetool can run....

If any one know kindly reply me as I need it very immediately.....

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the JMX port to 7199, then trying to connect to that using nodetool.  Problem is nodetool uses the Thrift port, which by default is 9160.

Answer (score -1):

Ive lost a lot of time trying to fix this, today finally did it
Just go to

C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\conf
and edit the file cassandra.yaml

Look for: `listen localhost` and change it for `listen x.x.x.x`
where `x.x.x.x` is the IP of the local host machine.

Restart Cassandra Service and be sure Windows firewall allows the connection.
Maybe you want to start with firewall off to check if nodetool is working.